# How can I call the desired function via jquery?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

It is necessary that when you click on the button, a request is made via ajax and the desired row in the database is deleted.
I have the code:

```
$(".remove_order_submit").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
    url: "/modules/ps_customercedula/ps_customercedula.php",
    method: "post",
    data: {
        method: 1,
        id_order_remove: {$hook_name}
    },
    success: function(data){
        
    }
});
  });
});
```

How to write php so that if post method = 1 then call the function

```
public function displayAjax()
    {
        $db = \Db::getInstance();
        if ($this->errors)
            die(Tools::jsonEncode(array('hasError' => true, 'errors' => $this->errors)));

        if(Tools::getValue('method')=='1')
        {
            $db = \Db::getInstance();
            $result = $db->delete('log', 'id_log = 2');
        
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use direct address of main PHP file of your module.

In admin side: you can use the configuration page of your module(getContent method) or in the better choice, you can create custom adminController in your module

In front side: you have to create frontController in your module

Comment: You need to complete the details of your question so that I can give you an example.

Comment: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/1052543-how-can-i-call-the-desired-function-via-jquery/?tab=comments